# How do I find all Users/Groups/Roles that have been given access to specific ListViews?

Tags: list-view

How do I Find/List/Query/Export/View
all Users/Groups/Roles that have been given access to specific ListViews?

I wish to remove accesss to external users.
I can retrieve via SFDX CLI
Here is an example of what I get when I retrieve
it does not contain any Sharing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ListView xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>All</fullName>
    <columns>NAME</columns>
    <columns>Contact__c</columns>
    <columns>Account__c</columns>
    <columns>Event__c</columns>
    <columns>Status__c</columns>
    <filterScope>Everything</filterScope>
    <filters>
        <field>CREATED_DATE</field>
        <operation>equals</operation>
        <value>TODAY</value>
    </filters>
    <label>All</label>
</ListView>
```

I want to retrieve/query all shares to users/groups/roles of every specific listview, especially public/external facing.

I know there is ListView object and UserListView, but it does not provide what I need, limited data is returned in a query.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this blog https://www.simplysfdc.com/2017/05/salesforce-list-view-sharedto.html

Author has explained very well with examples and pictures.

Note : Neither I am an author nor I am promoting the blog, I just found the article helpful and so posted here.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @identigral noted and will keep in mind when I answer next time.